# Just try and Understand this Riley riddle, bet You can't.

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

My Prefix is really good at this.

My Infix goes by quite fast.

My Suffix is adorable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is-

> Prosecute

Prefix-

> Pro, very good at something can be stated as being a pro at it.

Infix-

> Sec, seconds go by very fast.

Suffix-

> Cute, another word for adorable.

Title Hint-

> The capitalized letters in the title spell out JURY

Comment: Well done! Did you get the clue from the title?

Comment: not at first, just got it now, will add to the answer.